# WP-CLI installation over composer

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I'm working on a wordpress skeleton for practice. I've got a Composer project and installed the `wp-cli/wp-cli` dependency.

I want to create and run custom tasks with this `wp-cli`, for example to download the core of WordPress into this project. This because I'm not putting the core of wordpress into my git repository.

Because I have installed the `wp-cli/wp-cli` dependency only in my project and not globally over my local machine, I can't run the `wp ...` commands a normal terminal.

For my own research, I found out that I can use the [Command Line Tool Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6630-command-line-tool-support) in my IntelliJ IDE. With this plugin I can use the composer dependency to run commands with the `wp-cli`. I don't think this is the right solution, because everyone might have a different IDE and/or operating system.

How can I run `wp-cli` commands over the installation over Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running commands with `/vendor/bin/wp ....`. I found out I have to replace the `/` with a `\`.

To run commands from this binary, this syntax should be used like:

> `vendor\bin\wp ...`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are insisting from running wp-cli from composer rather from the machine? Since it is terminal command program that has access to create files and modify files why not install it on the machine.